# Create a class to connect to any database using jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to design a Java swing application. I want to experiment and use an MVC type of architecture whereby my UI is separated from the actual logic to access data and connect to a database. I have decided that I need to create a custom class that contains all the logic to connect to the database and then simply call methods from this class in my action event for any particular form and button. This way I can switch databases and all I need to do (if I have a large code base with many many forms) is change the JDBC connection string to connect to oracle instead of MySQL. So far I have the code to connect to a database but I am trying to figure out how I can make this a class.

```
try
     {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         Connection con=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prototypeeop","root","triala");
         Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

I will then return the result set from a member function of my connection class to process and display on the screen.

Comment: Use [DAO](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DataAccessObject.html) pattern.

Comment: that article seems too complex for me...i just want to create my own class with the above code...im sort of a beginner and need more guidance somewhat

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just create a separate class and delegate to him a getting of connection to database:

```
public class ConnectionManager {
    private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prototypeeop";    
    private static String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";   
    private static String username = "root";   
    private static String password = "triala";
    private static Connection con;
    private static String urlstring;

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
            try {
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(urlstring, username, password);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                // log an exception. fro example:
                System.out.println("Failed to create the database connection."); 
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            // log an exception. for example:
            System.out.println("Driver not found."); 
        }
        return con;
    }
}
```

Then get the connection in a code as follows:

```
private Connection con = null;
private Statement stmt = null;
private ResultSet rs = null;

con = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
stmt = con.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

Comment: thank you mate...your too cool....another question is if i have to change my database from mysql to postgress dont i just have to change the driver name and the string url in my class and then still use the same calls within my action events? sorry for novice questions

Comment: also is this class the data object access layer? how does it fit in the modevl view controller i guess

Comment: hey i am making this class and i get a classnotfound exception is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement? this has soemthign to do with my try and catch block and i am wondering what the problem is . It says for the try error that ....unreported excpetion java.lang.classnotfound excpetion  must be caught or declared before it is thrown? i apologize for the obvious questions but i am new to try and catch blocks too. I know it has somethignt o do with me not declaring this type of error because the SQLException has been declared in the java.sql package hence why i dont get an error

Comment: @rambokayambo the part of the class ConnectionManager() is correctly defined ,you just have to mention the property values according to your DataBase  ,and for the second part ,you can just mention the classname.methodName inside the main method(),thats what i have done.      `public static void main(String[]args){ ConnectionManager. getConnection()}` as the method is declared public static you can just write the className .methode() ,without declaring an Object for that method,I mean this has worked for me .and remember to add the external library for the DataBase

Comment: Why do you not throw an exception, e.g. `ex.printStackTrace();` instead of using `System.out.println();`? When the connection fails, the system out println are shown, but the code fails on a null pointer at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [MySQL JDBC Utilities](https://code.google.com/p/mysql-jdbc-utilities/) API for MySQL connectivity.

This API offers very cool features and also fulfill your requirement!

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can make it

1. Override determineCurrentLookupKey() method of Spring's [AbstractRoutingDataSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html) class.
2. You can create a class which will return Connection based on system.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use fancier stuff like [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/orm/) or if your database usage is simple then you can try [Commons DbUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/)

#### Ceremonial connection code

```
String db = "jdbc:h2:mem:;INIT=runscript from 'classpath:/prototypeeop.sql'"; 
//for H2 in-memory database:
Connection DriverManager.getConnection(db);
```

Remember the core classes and interfaces in **Commons DbUtils** are `QueryRunner` and `ResultSetHandler`.