# Can't connect to the database?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-connection

I'm making a simple registration program to practise. For this I need to connect to a database. I tried diffrent things, but nothing worked out

I'm using Xampp and MySQL Workbench. I did't set any password or username. On MySQL Workbench it says: 
Connection:
Name: demo
Host: 127.0.0.1
Port: 3306
Server: mariadb.org binary distribution
Version: 10.1.37-MariaDB
Connector: C++ 8.0.14
Login User: root
Current User: root@localhost
SSL: Disabled

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            // 1. Get connection to the database
        //  Connection myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo", "student", "student");
            //Connection myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/demo");
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mysql";
            Connection myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

            //2. Create a statement
            Statement myStatement = myConnection.createStatement();

            //3. execute sql query
            ResultSet myResultSet = myStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM students");

            //4. process the result set
            while(myResultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println(myResultSet.getString("lname") + ", " + myResultSet.getString("fname"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }



    }

}
```

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:827)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:447)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:237)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at jdbcdemo.Driver.main(Driver.java:14)
```

Comment: Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915375/create-a-class-to-connect-to-any-database-using-jdbc

Answer (score 2):

This answer is speculative, because I haven't actually tested it against MySQL, but here are two problems I see with your current approach:

- You mentioned that you didn't create any username or password.  However, as far as I know, even if you didn't create a username, then you would be using whatever default comes with MySQL (usually `root`).
- Not setting a password is possible, but in that case you should still be using the three parameter variant of `DriverManager.getConnection`, which accepts a JDBC URL, a username (the default), and a password (empty, in your case).

Putting this all together, you might try:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mysql";
Connection myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");
```

Then, try to use your connection assuming the above works.

Comment: Now I got even more errors. You are correct the username is "root"

Comment: What other errors are you getting? Your root user will need a password to connect through jdbc...

Answer (score 0):

The connection URL is in this format:

```
mysql://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<db_name>
```